# JUnit Mockito SpringMVC 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mocking, mockito

while testing spring mvc controller with JUnit and Mockito
got this line

`WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [application] in DispatcherServlet with name ''`

Does that mean that DispatcherServlet was not loaded? How to configure it properly? Thanks

test trace

```
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/application],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.resman.web.controller.ApplicationController.index(org.springframework.ui.Model,com.resman.service.user.DBAuthenticationService$CustomUser)
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/application/remove-app/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.resman.web.controller.ApplicationController.remove(java.lang.Long,com.resman.service.user.DBAuthenticationService$CustomUser)
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/application/profile-app/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.resman.web.controller.ApplicationController.findProfile(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.Long,com.resman.service.user.DBAuthenticationService$CustomUser)
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/application/create-app-form],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.resman.web.controller.ApplicationController.createApplicationForm(org.springframework.ui.Model)
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/application/create-app],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.resman.web.controller.ApplicationController.createApplication(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.util.Date,java.util.Date,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,com.resman.service.user.DBAuthenticationService$CustomUser) throws java.text.ParseException
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/application/edit-app],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.resman.web.controller.ApplicationController.editApplication(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.Long,int,java.util.Date,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long,com.resman.service.user.DBAuthenticationService$CustomUser)
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/application/all-apps],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.resman.web.controller.ApplicationController.findAll(org.springframework.ui.Model,com.resman.service.user.DBAuthenticationService$CustomUser)
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/application/find-for-approver],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.resman.web.controller.ApplicationController.findForApprover(org.springframework.ui.Model)
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/application/find-for-admin],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.resman.web.controller.ApplicationController.findForAdmin(org.springframework.ui.Model)
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext@34e9fd99
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet ''
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet '': initialization started
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:12 PM org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 2 ms
Jan 09, 2017 10:03:13 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [application] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:653)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:152)
    at com.resman.web.controller.ApplicationControllerTest.indexText(ApplicationControllerTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

class itself

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER =
            LogManager.getLogger(ApplicationController.class);
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationDAO applicationDAO;
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDAO;
    @Autowired
    private ResourceDao resourceDao;
    @Autowired
    private ResourceTypeService resourceTypeService;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationValidator applicationValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "application", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal DBAuthenticationService.CustomUser currentUser) {
        LOGGER.debug("application index page");
        model.addAttribute("userRole", currentUser.getUserRole());
        return "application/index";
    }
```

test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ApplicationControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private ApplicationDAO applicationDAO;

    @Mock
    private UserDao userDAO;

    @Mock
    private ResourceDao resourceDao;

    @Mock
    private ResourceTypeService resourceTypeService;

    @Mock
    private ApplicationValidator applicationValidator;

    @InjectMocks
    private ApplicationController controller;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
       this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void indexText() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("application")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.resman.*")
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE");
        dataSource.setUsername("project");
        dataSource.setPassword("projectsql");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionsManager() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return dataSourceTransactionManager;
    }
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="resourceManager" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the line

```
mockMvc.perform(get("application")).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

`"application"` should be changed to `"/application"` and everything will work

Answer (score 0):

probably you may need 
**default-servlet-handler**
in your AppConfig,

eg:

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
    }
```

Comment: thad did not help, same result